# Facebook Event Tracking - Button Tracking

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to track a button with the Facebook pixel. I have implemented the code but not sure it is correct and want to confirm it will only fire when clicked.

The code I have implemented is:

```
fbq('track', 'gform_submit_button_291');
```

Is this written correctly to only fire when clicked?

Can someone please provide this code in a full pixel example

Thanks so much guys!

Comment: That is a simple function call. It has nothing whatsoever to do with anything being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really saying anything with your question.

Have you included Facebook's official javascript snippet/code? Are you building your own from their API?

---

Edit:
From: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755?helpref=faq_content#createpixel

Your end code should [image: look like this]

is where you website's title, description, css styles and javascript should be. At the top of the page.

If all of this work, you should see the tracking happening from your facebook tracker

Comment: Thanks, Yes I have included the Facebook pixel on the page. I am trying to track the 'Download My Info Pack' button on this page https://macleay.edu.au/campaign/advertising-at-macleay-sydney-2017/

Comment: I've adjusted my answer, hope this helps.